# how to use imageMagick with C#

Tags: c#, image, pdf, imagemagick

Could you explain how I can use ImageMagick with C# . I am trying to convert PDF to pages into images.

I want to run imageMagick command "convert -density 300 $input.pdf $output.png"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string arguments = string.Format(@"-density 300 {0}.pdf {1}.png", intputFileName, outputFileName");
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
    Arguments = arguments,
    Filename = @"C:\path\to\imagick\convert.exe"
};
Process.Start(startInfo).WaitForExit();
```

References:

- [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo_properties.aspx)
- [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Comment: thanx. Is there a way to hide the command prompt(stop popping the command prompt) ? Thanks again. Very much helpful!

Comment: If you need hide console you looking for hstart tool http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html.

Comment: try `startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true`

Comment: startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; this one works, thanks! thank u 1000 times :)

Answer (score 9):

Magic.Net is a C# port for popular library ImageMagick. Install Magick.Net using Nuget package from url https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU/ . Note that there are many versions of Magick.Net so select as per your need. This way you can use C#. See code below

Note it will append images vertically. Similarly you can append horizontally.

```
using ImageMagick;

string inputPdf= @"C:\my docs\input.pdf";
string outputPng= @"C:\my docs\output.png";

using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    images.Read(inputPdf);
    using (IMagickImage vertical = images.AppendVertically())
        {
            vertical.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
            vertical.Density = new Density(300);  
            vertical.Write(outputPng);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use Magick.NET, no need to install ImageMagick on clients:
http://magick.codeplex.com/

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that Magick.NET requires GhostScript to convert PDF to images, which is *not* free.  And is odd, because simply using ImageMagick from the command line doesn't require Ghostscript to convert pdf's to images.